# How to generate an array of unique objects from api?

Tags: javascript, arrays, axios, javascript-objects

I'm trying to disable booked times from calendar, depending on the date. My goal is to create an array, which holds objects with single date and array of booked times.
I have created an api, which outputs something like this:

```
"bookings": [
    {
     "_id": "5ce1b8792598adasf452",
     "workType": "Nail polishing",
     "client": "Mary Johnson",
     "date": "2019-05-31T00:00:00.000Z",
     "bookingTime": "09:00"
    },
    {
     "_id": "5ce1b8753hs53gasf452",
     "workType": "Makeup",
     "client": "Kate Bush",
     "date": "2019-05-31T00:00:00.000Z",
     "bookingTime": "10:00"
    }
]
```

I've tried using Sets, filters, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to implement it to my own code.

Snippet of my code:

```
bookedTimes: []

fetchBookedTimes() {
      axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/bookings").then(res => {
        for (var i = 0; i < res.data.bookings.length; i++) {
          this.bookedTimes.push({
            date: moment(res.data.bookings[i].date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            times: [res.data.bookings[i].bookingTime.substring(0,2)]
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

I expect the output to be

```
bookedTimes: [
        {
          date: "2019-05-31",
          times: ["09", "10"]
        },
        {
          date: "2019-06-01",
          times: ["10", "11"]
        }
      ]
```

But the actual output is

```
bookedTimes: [
        {
          date: "2019-05-31",
          times: ["09"]
        },
        {
          date: "2019-05-31",
          times: ["10"]
        },
        {
          date: "2019-06-01",
          times: ["10"]
        },
        {
          date: "2019-06-01",
          times: ["11"]
        }
      ]
```

Comment: From where the date `"2019-06-01"` comes in your expected output?

Comment: I wanted to make my point clear by creating a mock object. Sorry if it caused confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code, the actual output is correct. You are looping the response and pushing the data to an array. If you want to group them by date, then you have to create an object and then convert it to the expected output.

```
var result = res.data.bookings.reduce(function (defaultValue, booking) {
    var date = moment(booking.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    defaultValue[date] = defaultValue[date] || {date: date, times: []};
    defaultValue[date].times.push(booking.bookingTime.substring(0,2));
    return defaultValue;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing values directly into array but you need to group them by date so you can use an object and then push values to array in the end

- Here temp is used to group values by date
- We check for date it exists we push the time value to times array if not we create a new property on temp
- In the end we push values to `this.bookedTimes` array

---

```
fetchBookedTimes() {
      axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/bookings").then(res => {
        let temp = {}
        for (var i = 0; i < res.data.bookings.length; i++) {
          let date = moment(res.data.bookings[i].date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
          let time = [res.data.bookings[i].bookingTime.substring(0,2)]
          temp[date] = temp[date] || {date: date, times:[]}
          temp[date].times.push(time)
          });
        }
      this.bookedTimes.push(Object.values(temp))
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `reduce()`

```js
const arr = [
    {
     "_id": "5ce1b8792598adasf452",
     "workType": "Nail polishing",
     "client": "Mary Johnson",
     "date": "2019-05-31T00:00:00.000Z",
     "bookingTime": "09:00"
    },
    {
     "_id": "5ce1b8753hs53gasf452",
     "workType": "Makeup",
     "client": "Kate Bush",
     "date": "2019-05-31T00:00:00.000Z",
     "bookingTime": "10:00"
    },
    {
     "_id": "5ce1b8753hs53gasf452",
     "workType": "Makeup",
     "client": "Kate Bush",
     "date": "2019-06-31T00:00:00.000Z",
     "bookingTime": "11:00"
    },
    {
     "_id": "5ce1b8753hs53gasf452",
     "workType": "Makeup",
     "client": "Kate Bush",
     "date": "2019-06-31T00:00:00.000Z",
     "bookingTime": "12:00"
    }
]


const res = arr.reduce((ac,{date,bookingTime}) => {
  ac[date] = ac[date] || {date,bookingTime:[]}

  ac[date].bookingTime.push(bookingTime.slice(0,2));
  return ac;

},{})
console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: You should include date format as in OP's original code else it will add two different dates even if there's a difference in just time i.e `"2019-06-31T00:00:01.000Z` and `"2019-06-31T00:00:00.000Z`

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the date of already in the array. Check if 'times' already exist in 'object.times', if not, push it to the 'object.times' array.
Please see the code below.

```
const date = moment(res.data.bookings[i].date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
const times = res.data.bookings[i].bookingTime.substring(0, 2);

const arrayIndex = bookedTimes.findIndex(item => item.date === date);
//Check if date already exist in array
if (arrayIndex !== -1) {
  //Check if 'times' already exist in 'object.times'
  if (!bookedTimes[arrayIndex].times.includes(times)) {
    //Push 'times' in 'object.times'
    bookedTimes[arrayIndex].times.push(times);
  }
} else {
 //Push a new object into the array
  bookedTimes.push({
    date: date,
    times: [times]
  });
}
```